# Custom Domain Nameservers?

Tags: nameserver, domain-name

We are a small marketing company that does web design. One of our services we offer is we host our clients websites along with the service.

Recently we purchased an in-house server that we could host the sites on so it's easier for us to manage. It's running CPanel and everything is setup correctly as we can access all of it.

Before, we were using Inmotion Hosting, and previously our clients would go to their domain settings and change their nameservers to `ns1.inmotionhosting.com` and `ns2.inmotionhosting.com`.

Now that we have our own server, we want people to change their nameservers to `ns1.OURCOMPANY.example` and `ns2.OURCOMPANY.example`.

Our domain is with GoDaddy, we've gone to the "host names" section of the domain settings and added entries for ns1 and ns2, both pointing to our server's IP address. We've also gone in the WHM settings and made sure the nameservers were correlated on there as well.

Then when we go and change the nameservers of one of our clients domains to `ns1.OURCOMPANY.example` and `ns2.OURCOMPANY.example`, it never points to it (we've waited over 5 days so it's not a "propagation" issue)

TLDR; We want custom nameservers that our clients can use, such as `ns1.OURCOMPANY.example` and `ns2.OURCOMPANY.example`, to point their domains to our web server that just has a static IP.

Comment: Why do you want your clients to change their name servers? You're hosting their websites, right? If so, leave their DNS alone unless you have specific and expert level DNS hosting experience and have the requisite geo-diverse and highly available infrastructure to do it.

Comment: @joeqwerty They have to change their nameservers because we're not using inmotion anymore. Their websites will go down because we won't be paying them anymore. Did you even read the post?

Comment: Did I read your post? Yes, I read it. Where does it state that you're not using Inmotion for DNS? I see some information about websites and Inmotion and how you're moving their websites to your own server. Was I supposed to assume that you were moving name servers too? At any rate, my comment stands. Unless you have specific and expert level DNS hosting experience and have the requisite geo-diverse and highly available infrastructure to do it, then you should not be hosting their DNS. Move each client's DNS back to their Domain Name Registrar and leave it there.

Comment: No one can really help you since you obfuscated everything. If you are not sure about your DNS configurations, first try with a non production domain, do the changes and use online troubleshooting tools like DNSViz or Zonemaster. Until those tools give you the green light, it means your configuration is not good and you should not proceed with your customers domains. Also DNS and webhosting at some scale needs specific knowledge and expertise if you are not sure you would give a better service to your clients by using external providers. The names of the nameservers have no specific value.